# Ui-date timepicker - angular js . - Can't close the timepicker box by click on the input

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, timepicker

Im using the simple demo of uidatetimepicker

https://rawgit.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker/master/example/index.html

The difference is that i'm not using the clock icon - I have `ng-click` action in the input field so I want the input will also click the time form and no just open it so:

First click will open the timebox

Second click on the input, close the box, and now only click outside the box will close it

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" 
         ng-click="ctrl.openCalendar($event, 'picker2')" 
         class="form-control" 
         datetime-picker="HH:mm" ng-model="ctrl.picker2.date" 
         is-open="ctrl.picker2.open" 
         enable-date="false" 
         timepicker-options="ctrl.picker2.timepickerOptions" 
         close-on-selection="true">
</p>
```

Comment: can you provied a fiddle? the question is not so clear...

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngFocus`and `ngBlur` instead of `ngClick`. Clicking opens the input field for editing, so you may want to associate the opening of the widget with user clicking on the field, and moving away as closing of the widget.

However, IMO, having the input field directly editable is better anyway, since it provides the savvy user with a shortcut.